# Text over Image html css

Tags: css, html, image, text, css-position

I'm trying to set an image in HTML and want text to run over it. But when I use the following code the text will run under the image.

HTML

```
    <div id="titel">
    <img src="images/titel.jpg" alt="titel">
    <h3>Titel</h3>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #titel
    {
        float:left;
        width:220px;
        height:100px;
        margin:0px 5px 5px;
    }

    h2
    {
        position:absolute;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `position:relative` to the titel div and a top value to the image.

```
  #titel {
      float:left;
      width:220px;
      height:100px;
      margin:0px 5px 5px;
      position:relative;
  }
  h3 {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
  }
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bktn9/1/)**

Another option is to set the image as the background image of the div, and dispense with the positioning altogether.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/s9AHb/)**

(note also that in your example you have a `h3` element but in your CSS you were targeting a `h2` element.)

Comment: Also can set `z-index:1` to keep text over image.

Comment: @Danko - you would still need to set a top position and also set a relative position on the parent div.

Comment: Yeph I mean In addition can set the `z-index` value

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index:

```
img
 { position:absolute;
   z-index:-1;
 }
```

z-index defines the stack order of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Use image as the background and add text to it .

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
 body 
 {
 background-image:url('images/titel.jpg');
 }
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <h3>Titel</h3>
 </body>
 </html>
```